# How to pad values in a virtual MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have a solution that works, but I'd like to know if anyone can come up with a better way to get the same result.

I have two tables, one for **devices** and one for **lines**. Every device can have plugged in 0 to 4 lines. The query I'm running is just to get the settings for the lines of a single device. So, I filter the **devices** table to return only one row. Since I need the outcome in a single row, I'm using `GROUP_CONCAT`.

The devices have a MAC address, and I'm filtering the devices for that value.

Example of `Devices` table

```
+-------------+------------------+

| DeviceID    | MACAddress       |

+-------------+------------------+

| 900         | 'FFFFBBBB5555' |

+-------------+------------------+
```

Example of `Lines` table

```
+---------+-------------+-----------------+-------------------+

| LineID | DeviceID | LineNumber | Settings |

+---------+-------------+-----------------+-------------------+

| 100    | 900      | 1          | '{"scan":240, "enabled":true}'

| 101    | 900      | 3          | '{"scan":30, "enabled":false}'

+---------+-------------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

-- *sorry for the table layouts, I have no idea how to build a good table in starkoverflow.com* :( --

The query I'm running is to get the Line Settings for the 4 possible lines the device can have. So I always need 4 settings and fill in the gaps with null.

```
SELECT
    Devices.DeviceID,    
    CONCAT( '[', GROUP_CONCAT( IFNULL( Lines.Settings, 'null' ) ORDER BY pad.LineNumber ), ']' ) AS settings_json_array
FROM
    Devices
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS LineNumber
        UNION SELECT 2 AS LineNumber
        UNION SELECT 3 AS LineNumber
        UNION SELECT 4 AS LineNumber
    ) pad
        ON true 
    LEFT JOIN Lines
        ON ( Lines.DeviceID = Devices.DeviceID AND Lines.LineNumber = pad.LineNumber )
WHERE
    Devices.MACAddress='FFFFBBBB5555';
```

The outcome is a single row

```
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| DeviceID | settings_json_array |

+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| 900      | '[{"scan":240, "enabled":true},null,{"scan":30, "enabled":false},null]' |

+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'd like to get rid of the ugly `pad` virtual table

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the pad derived table?

Comment: Too much UNION statements, I was wondering if there is a fancier solution. ;)

Comment: Have a real table with 1 field, with 4 records, with 1-4 as values. SQL cannot select what is not there, so you have to produce the 4 records somehow.

Comment: Thanks @rahul-tripathi.

Comment: Thanks Shadow, but I'd rather keep the derived table then. ;)

Comment: As @Shadow is saying it would be a Helper table. Albeit of not tremendous use perhaps for your org. But people have them, especially for dates, left joins, and for reports (missing days of work, that sort of thing). A helper table here --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/37739514

Comment: Thanks Drew and Shadow, I don't see so ugly the `pad` table anymore. ;)