# MySql Select and count number of data per day - include empty dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

How to select & group data from the database by day, but also include days without an entry. In that case, the value would be 0.

If not doable with MySQL, could also use PHP.

Here's what I currently have:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS the_date
     , COUNT(*) AS count 
  FROM table 
 WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2016-11-28', '%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2016-12-05', '%Y-%m-%d') 
 GROUP 
    BY the_date
```

Comment: show the output of `show create table myTableName` ... I assume you have it not as a `DATE` or `DATETIME` format. It sounds like you need a Helper table for a left join. See this helper table answer of mine [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37739514). Permanent helper tables scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be simpler to add the missing dates in PHP.  In MySQL, you need to get the dates from somewhere.  Often, databases have a "calendar" table with this information.  If you have one, then something like this does what you want:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(c.date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS the_date, COUNT(t.date) AS count 
FROM Calendar c LEFT JOIN
     table t
     ON c.date = t.date
WHERE c.date BETWEEN '2014-11-28' AND '2014-12-05' -- MySQL recognizes strings in the format of YYYY-MM-DD as dates when needed
GROUP BY the_date;
```

If you don't have such a table, you can make one for the query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(c.date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS the_date, COUNT(t.date) AS count 
FROM (SELECT date('2014-11-28') as date UNION ALL
      SELECT date('2014-11-29') as date UNION ALL
      SELECT date('2014-11-30') as date UNION ALL
      SELECT date('2014-12-01') as date UNION ALL
      SELECT date('2014-12-02') as date UNION ALL
      SELECT date('2014-12-03') as date UNION ALL
      SELECT date('2014-12-04') as date UNION ALL
      SELECT date('2014-12-05') as date 
     ) c LEFT JOIN
     table t
     ON c.date = t.date
GROUP BY the_date;
```

This works for a small number of dates but is not going to work so well for ranges that span months or years.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I went with the calendar solution but it returns 1 even if there's no match in the table. Works perfectly on other occasions, though!

Comment: Seems like replacing `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(t.ID)`

Comment: One more specification, is there any possible way to have a condition in WHERE, related to table but it also has display row when there is no match for the table. Hope you understand my question. `WHERE rdfa_Sessions.conversion = 'true' AND rdfa_Calendar.day BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2014-11-28', '%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2017-12-05', '%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: @SilverRingvee . . . That condition should go in the `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how can I add the missing dates in PHP?

Comment: @alex . . . If you have a question, ask it as a question rather than in a comment.